# Arrival time cannot be sorted correctly in Java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

Greeting to everyone. I currently work on a program that sorting the emergency number of patients(the number that assigned by nurse when they enter the emergency room and this number determines the seriousness of their sickness too). However, if there are more than 1 patient who hold the same emergency numbers(eg: 2 patients hold emergency number 1), the one who came earlier should receive the treatment first. For this reason, I have 2 sortings, one is to sort the emergency number in ascending order and the other is to sort the time in ascending order too. But unfortunately the second sorting cannot work correctly.The following are the explanations for the type of emergency numbers:

Emergency number : 1 – Immediately life threatening
Emergency number : 2 – Urgent, but not immediately life threatening
Emergency number : 3 – Less urgent

So,now comes the coding part(Please note that this is a linkedlist)

Interface:

```
public interface ListInterface<T> {

  public boolean add(T newEntry);

  public boolean add(int newPosition, T newEntry);

  public T remove(int givenPosition);

  public void clear();

  public boolean replace(int givenPosition, T newEntry);

  public T getEntry(int givenPosition);

  public boolean contains(T anEntry);

  public int getLength();

  public boolean isEmpty();

  public boolean isFull();
}
```

LList class:

```
/**
 * LList.java
 * A class that implements the ADT list by using a chain of nodes,
 * with the node implemented as an inner class.
 */
public class LList<T> implements ListInterface<T> {
    private Node firstNode; // reference to first node
    private int  length;    // number of entries in list

    public LList() {
        clear();
    } 

    public final void clear() {
        firstNode = null;
        length = 0;
    } 

    public boolean add(T newEntry) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newEntry);  // create the new node

        if (isEmpty())                              // if empty list
            firstNode = newNode;
        else {                        // add to end of nonempty list
            Node currentNode = firstNode;                   // traverse linked list with p pointing to the current node
            while (currentNode.next != null) {      // while have not reached the last node
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }
            currentNode.next = newNode; // make last node reference new node
        } 

        length++;
        return true;
    }  

  public boolean add(int newPosition, T newEntry) { // OutOfMemoryError possible
        boolean isSuccessful = true;

        if ((newPosition >= 1) && (newPosition <= length+1)) {
            Node newNode = new Node(newEntry);

            if (isEmpty() || (newPosition == 1))    {     // case 1: add to beginning of list
                newNode.next = firstNode;
                firstNode = newNode;
            }
            else {                                                    // case 2: list is not empty and newPosition > 1
                Node nodeBefore = firstNode;
                for (int i = 1; i < newPosition - 1; ++i) {
                    nodeBefore = nodeBefore.next;       // advance nodeBefore to its next node
                }

                newNode.next = nodeBefore.next; // make new node point to current node at newPosition
                nodeBefore.next = newNode;      // make the node before point to the new node
            } 

            length++;
        }
        else
            isSuccessful = false;

        return isSuccessful;
    } 

    public T remove(int givenPosition) {
      T result = null;                 // return value

      if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= length)) {
        if (givenPosition == 1) {      // case 1: remove first entry
          result = firstNode.data;     // save entry to be removed
          firstNode = firstNode.next;
        }
        else {                         // case 2: givenPosition > 1
            Node nodeBefore = firstNode;
                for (int i = 1; i < givenPosition - 1; ++i) {
                    nodeBefore = nodeBefore.next;       // advance nodeBefore to its next node
                }
                result = nodeBefore.next.data;  // save entry to be removed
                nodeBefore.next = nodeBefore.next.next; // make node before point to node after the
        }                                                               // one to be deleted (to disconnect node from chain)

        length--;
      } 

      return result;                   // return removed entry, or
                                       // null if operation fails
    } 

    public boolean replace(int givenPosition, T newEntry) {
        boolean isSuccessful = true;

    if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= length)) {
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
            for (int i = 0; i < givenPosition - 1; ++i) {
                // System.out.println("Trace| currentNode.data = " + currentNode.data + "\t, i = " + i);
                currentNode = currentNode.next;     // advance currentNode to next node
            }
            currentNode.data = newEntry;    // currentNode is pointing to the node at givenPosition
    }
        else
            isSuccessful = false;

        return isSuccessful;
  } 

  public T getEntry(int givenPosition) {
    T result = null;  

        if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= length)) {
            Node currentNode = firstNode;
            for (int i = 0; i < givenPosition - 1; ++i) {
                currentNode = currentNode.next;     // advance currentNode to next node
            }
            result = currentNode.data;  // currentNode is pointing to the node at givenPosition
    } 

    return result;
  } 

    public boolean contains(T anEntry) {
        boolean found = false;
        Node currentNode = firstNode;

        while (!found && (currentNode != null)) {
            if (anEntry.equals(currentNode.data))
                found = true;
            else
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
        } 

        return found;
    } 

  public int getLength() {
     return length;
  } 

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    boolean result;

    if (length == 0)  
        result = true;
    else
        result = false;

    return result;
  } 

  public boolean isFull() {
     return false;
  } 

  public String toString() {
    String outputStr = "";
      Node currentNode = firstNode;
        while (currentNode != null) {
            outputStr += currentNode.data + "\n";
          currentNode = currentNode.next;
        } 
        return outputStr;
  } 

    private class Node {
    private T    data; 
    private Node next; 

        private Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        } 

        private Node(T data, Node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        } 
    } // end Node

} // end LList
```

Patient class:

```
public class Patient {

    private int emergencyNo;
    private int queueTime;  
    private String patientName;
    private String patientIC;
    private String patientGender;
    private String patientTelNo;
    private String patientAdd;
    private String visitDate;

    public Patient() {
    }

    public Patient(int emergencyNo, int queueTime, String patientName, String patientIC, String patientGender, String patientTelNo, String patientAdd, String visitDate)
    {
        this.emergencyNo = emergencyNo;
        this.queueTime = queueTime;
        this.patientName = patientName;
        this.patientIC = patientIC;
        this.patientGender = patientGender;
        this.patientTelNo = patientTelNo;
        this.patientAdd = patientAdd;
        this.visitDate = visitDate;
    }

    //set methods
    public void setQueueTime(int queueTime)
    {
        this.queueTime = queueTime;
    }

    public boolean setEmergencyNo(int emergencyNo)
    {
        boolean varEmergencyNo = true;

        if (emergencyNo != 1 && emergencyNo != 2 && emergencyNo != 3)
        {
            varEmergencyNo = false;

            System.out.println("Emergency number is in invalid format!");
            System.out.println("Emergency number is either 1, 2 or 3 only!");
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

        else
        {
            this.emergencyNo = emergencyNo;
        }

        return varEmergencyNo;  
    }

    public boolean setPatientName(String patientName)
    {
        boolean varPatientName = true;

        if (patientName.equals("")  || patientName.equals(null))
        {
            varPatientName = false;

            System.out.println("The patient name cannot be empty!\n");
        }

        else
        {
            this.patientName = patientName;
        }

        return varPatientName;  
    }

    public boolean setPatientIC(String patientIC)
    {
        boolean varPatientIC = true;

        if(!patientIC.matches("^[0-9]{12}$"))
        {
            varPatientIC = false;

            System.out.println("IC is in invalid format!");
            System.out.println("It must consist of 12 numbers only!\n");
        }

        else
        {
            this.patientIC = patientIC;
        }

        return varPatientIC;
    }

    public boolean setPatientGender(String patientGender)
    {
        boolean varPatientGender = true;

        if(!patientGender.equals("F") && !patientGender.equals("f") && !patientGender.equals("M") && !patientGender.equals("m"))
        {
            varPatientGender = false;

            System.out.println("Gender is in invalid format!");
            System.out.println("It must be either 'M' or 'F' only!\n");
        }

        else
        {
            this.patientGender = patientGender;
        }

        return varPatientGender;
    }

    public boolean setPatientTelNo(String patientTelNo) 
    {
        boolean varPatientTelNo = true;

        if((!patientTelNo.matches("^01[02346789]\\d{7}$")) && (!patientTelNo.matches("^03\\d{8}$")))
        {
            varPatientTelNo = false;

            System.out.println("Invalid phone number!");
            System.out.println("It must be in the following format : 0167890990 / 0342346789!\n");
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        else
        {
            this.patientTelNo = patientTelNo;
        }

        return varPatientTelNo;
    }

    public boolean setPatientAdd(String patientAdd)
    {
        boolean varPatientAdd = true;

        if (patientAdd.equals("")  || patientAdd.equals(null))
        {
            varPatientAdd = false;

            System.out.println("The patient address cannot be empty!\n");
        }

        else
        {
            this.patientAdd = patientAdd;
        }

        return varPatientAdd;   
    }

    public void setVisitDate(String visitDate)
    {
        this.visitDate = visitDate;
    }

    //get methods
    public int getQueueTime()
    {
        return this.queueTime;
    }

    public int getEmergencyNo()
    {
        return this.emergencyNo;
    }

    public String getPatientName()
    {
        return this.patientName;
    }

    public String getPatientIC()
    {
        return this.patientIC;
    }

    public String getPatientGender()
    {
        return this.patientGender;
    }

    public String getPatientTelNo() 
    {
        return this.patientTelNo;
    }

    public String getPatientAdd()
    {
        return this.patientAdd;
    }

    public String getVisitDate()
    {
        return this.visitDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return (this.emergencyNo + "\t\t" + this.patientName + "\t\t" + this.patientIC + 
            "\t\t" + this.patientGender + "\t\t" + this.patientTelNo + "\t\t" + this.patientAdd + "\t\t" + this.visitDate);
    }

    public String anotherToString()
    {
        return (this.emergencyNo + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + this.patientName + "\t\t\t " + this.visitDate);
    }
}
```

EmergencyCmp(Comparator)--->use for sorting the emergency numbers of the patients

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class EmergencyCmp implements Comparator<Patient>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Patient p1, Patient p2) 
    {
        if(p1.getEmergencyNo() > p2.getEmergencyNo())
        {
            return 1;
        } 

        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
     }
}
```

QueueCmp(Comparator)--->use for sorting the arrival time of the patients

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class QueueCmp implements Comparator<Patient>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Patient p1, Patient p2) 
    {
        if(p1.getQueueTime() > p2.getQueueTime())
        {
             return 1;
        } 

        else
        {
             return -1;
        }
    }   
}
```

Main function:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*; 

public class DSA {

    public DSA() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //patient's attributes
        int emergencyNo;
        int queueTime;
        String patientName;
        String patientIC;
        String patientGender;
        String patientTelNo;
        String patientAdd;
        String visitDate;

        //counter
        int j = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        int count3 = 0;
        int countEnteredPatient = 1;
        int totalCount = 0;

        //calendar
        int nowYr, nowMn, nowDy, nowHr, nowMt, nowSc;

        //others
        boolean enterNewPatient = true;
        String continueInput;
        boolean enterNewPatient1 = true;
        String continueInput1;
        boolean continueEmergencyNo;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ListInterface<Patient> patientList = new LList<Patient>();
        ListInterface<Patient> newPatientList = new LList<Patient>();
        Patient[] patientArr1 = new Patient[10000];
        Patient[] patientArr2  = new Patient[10000];
        Patient[] patientArr3  = new Patient[10000];
        Patient tempoPatient;

        do{
            //do-while loop for entering new patient details after viewing patient list

            System.out.println("Welcome to Hospital Ten Stars!\n");

            do{
                //do-while loop for entering new patient details
                System.out.println("Entering details of patient " + countEnteredPatient);
                System.out.println("===================================\n");

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                nowYr = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                nowMn = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                nowDy = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                nowHr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                nowMt = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                nowSc = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                queueTime = calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

                visitDate = nowDy + "/" + nowMn + "/" + nowYr + ", " + nowHr + ":" + nowMt + ":" + nowSc;

                //input emergency number
                do{
                    tempoPatient = new Patient();

                    continueEmergencyNo = false;
                    int EmergencyNoOption;

                    try
                    {
                        do{
                            System.out.print("Please select 1 – Immediately life threatening, 2 – Urgent, but not immediately life threatening or 3 – Less urgent(Eg: 1) : ");
                            EmergencyNoOption = scan.nextInt();
                            scan.nextLine();
                            System.out.print("\n");

                          }while(tempoPatient.setEmergencyNo(EmergencyNoOption) == false);
                    }

                    catch(InputMismatchException ex)
                    {
                        System.out.print("\n");
                        System.out.println("Invalid input detected.");
                        scan.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("\n");

                        continueEmergencyNo = true;
                    }
                  }while(continueEmergencyNo);

                  //input patient name
                  do{
                        System.out.print("Patient name(Eg: Christine Redfield) : ");
                        patientName = scan.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }while(tempoPatient.setPatientName(patientName) == false);

                  //input patient ic no
                  do{
                        System.out.print("Patient IC number(Eg: 931231124567) : ");
                        patientIC = scan.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("\n");
                     }while(tempoPatient.setPatientIC(patientIC) == false);

                  //input patient gender    
                  do{
                        System.out.print("Patient gender(Eg: M) : ");
                        patientGender = scan.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }while(tempoPatient.setPatientGender(patientGender) == false);

                  //input patient tel. no
                  do{
                        System.out.print("Patient tel.No(without'-')(Eg: 0162345678/0342980123) : ");
                        patientTelNo = scan.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }while(tempoPatient.setPatientTelNo(patientTelNo) == false);

                  //input patient address
                  do{
                        System.out.print("Patient address(Eg: 4-C9 Jln Besar 123, Taman Besar, 56000 Kuala Lumpur) : ");
                        patientAdd = scan.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }while(tempoPatient.setPatientAdd(patientAdd) == false);

                  tempoPatient.setQueueTime(queueTime);
                  tempoPatient.setVisitDate(visitDate);             
                  patientList.add(tempoPatient);

                  //decide whether want to enter a new patient or not   
                  do{
                        System.out.print("Do you want to enter another new patient?(Eg: Y/N) : ");
                        continueInput = scan.nextLine();

                        if(continueInput.equals("Y") || continueInput.equals("y"))
                        {
                            enterNewPatient = true;

                            System.out.print("\n");
                        }

                        else if(continueInput.equals("N") || continueInput.equals("n"))
                        {
                            enterNewPatient = false;
                        }

                        else
                        {   
                            System.out.println("\n");
                            System.out.println("Please enter Y/N only.\n");
                        }

                    }while(!continueInput.equals("Y") && !continueInput.equals("y") && !continueInput.equals("N") && !continueInput.equals("n"));

                countEnteredPatient++;
            }while(enterNewPatient);    //end do-while loop for entering new patient details

            System.out.println("\nWaiting list of patient will be displayed soon.\n");

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            System.out.println("Waiting list of patients");
            System.out.println("========================\n");
            System.out.println("Number\t\tEmergency number\t\tPatient name\t\t ArrivalTime");
            System.out.println("============================================================================");

            for(int i = 1; i <= patientList.getLength(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + "\t\t\t" + patientList.getEntry(i).anotherToString());
            }

            do{
                    System.out.print("\nSo, now do you want to enter another new patient?(Eg: Y/N) : ");
                    continueInput1 = scan.nextLine();

                    if(continueInput1.equals("Y") || continueInput1.equals("y"))
                    {
                        enterNewPatient1 = true;

                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }

                    else if(continueInput1.equals("N") || continueInput1.equals("n"))
                    {
                        enterNewPatient1 = false;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("\n");
                        System.out.println("Please enter Y/N only.\n");
                    }

              }while(!continueInput1.equals("Y") && !continueInput1.equals("y") && !continueInput1.equals("N") && !continueInput1.equals("n"));

          }while(enterNewPatient1);//end do-while loop for entering new patient details after viewing patient list

        System.out.println("\nNow rearranging the list based on the seriouness and their arrival time.");

        try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        //create an unsorted array
        Patient[] tempoPatientArr = new Patient[patientList.getLength()];

        //copy the contents of patientList into tempoPatientArr
        for(int i = 1; i <= patientList.getLength(); i++ )
        {
            tempoPatientArr[i-1] = patientList.getEntry(i);
        }

        //sort tempoPatientArr
        Arrays.sort(tempoPatientArr, new EmergencyCmp());
        //the above part until this comment line does not have problem

        //check the emergency no and then categorise accordingly
        for(int i = 0; i < tempoPatientArr.length; i++)
        {
            if(tempoPatientArr[i].getEmergencyNo() == 1)
            {
                patientArr1[x] = tempoPatientArr[i];

                x++;
            }

            else if(tempoPatientArr[i].getEmergencyNo() == 2)
            {
                patientArr2[y] = tempoPatientArr[i];

                y++;
            }

            else if(tempoPatientArr[i].getEmergencyNo() == 3)
            {
                patientArr3[z] = tempoPatientArr[i];

                z++;
            }
        }

        //to check how many !null elements by using count for 3 sub-arrays
        for(int i = 0; i < patientArr1.length; i++)
        {
            if(patientArr1[i] != null)
            {
                count1++;
            }

            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < patientArr2.length; i++)
        {
            if(patientArr2[i] != null)
            {
                count2++;
            }

            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < patientArr3.length; i++)
        {
            if(patientArr3[i] != null)
            {
                count3++;
            }

            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        //new array with elimination of null values
        Patient[] newPatientArr1 = new Patient[count1];
        Patient[] newPatientArr2 = new Patient[count2];
        Patient[] newPatientArr3 = new Patient[count3];

        //copy the contents of old sub arrays(the arrays with null values) into the new sub arrays(without null values)
        for(int i = 0; i < newPatientArr1.length; i++)
        {
            newPatientArr1[i] = patientArr1[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < newPatientArr2.length; i++)
        {
            newPatientArr2[i] = patientArr2[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < newPatientArr3.length; i++)
        {
            newPatientArr3[i] = patientArr3[i];
        }

        totalCount = count1 + count2 + count3;

        //array that used to combine all the sub-arrays
        Patient[] newPatientArr = new Patient[totalCount];

        //sort all sub new arrays
        Arrays.sort(newPatientArr1, new QueueCmp());
        Arrays.sort(newPatientArr2, new QueueCmp());
        Arrays.sort(newPatientArr3, new QueueCmp());

        //combine the contents of sub new arrays into the newPatientArr array
        do{
            for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++)
            {
                newPatientArr[j] = newPatientArr1[i];

                j++;
            }

            for (int b = 0; b < count2; b++)
            {
                newPatientArr[j] = newPatientArr2[b];

                j++;
            }

            for (int c = 0; c < count3; c++)
            {
                newPatientArr[j] = newPatientArr3[c];

                j++;
            }

        }while(j < totalCount);

        //relink the nodes
        for(int i = 0; i < newPatientArr.length; i++)
        {
            newPatientList.add(newPatientArr[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("\nSorted waiting list of patients");
        System.out.println("===============================\n");
        System.out.println("Number\t\tEmergency number\t\tPatient name\t\t ArrivalTime");
        System.out.println("============================================================================");

        for(int i = 1; i <= newPatientList.getLength(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i + "\t\t\t" + newPatientList.getEntry(i).anotherToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Interface and LList class definitely do not have problems. So everyone can skip the 2 parts.

For the main function, I have a comment like this:

```
//the above part until this comment line does not have problem
```

When you all see the comment, that means the previous code does not have problem and you all may skip it and below is an attachment of the result that I got earlier:

[image]

So, from the picture you all can see that the sorting of arrival time is not correct. I hope that I can know why does this problem occurs since I cannot figure it out by myself. Thanks to all of you first.

So, after taking the advice of @Scott Hunter, I have made the following modification to the EmergencyCmp:

```
    @Override
    public int compare(Patient p1, Patient p2) 
    {
        int value = 0;

        if(p1.getEmergencyNo() > p2.getEmergencyNo())
        {
            value = 1;
        } 

        else if(p1.getEmergencyNo() < p2.getEmergencyNo())
        {
            value = -1;
        }

        else if(p1.getEmergencyNo() == p2.getEmergencyNo())
        {
            if(p1.getQueueTime() > p2.getQueueTime())
            {
                 return 1;
            } 

            else
            {
                 return -1;
            }
        }

        return value;
     }
```

However, the time sorting still produce a wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it (which I may not; you provided a LOT of extraneous stuff), it looks like you are trying to perform 2 distinct sorts, one after the other, such that the second is undoing the work of the first.  Instead, you should define a single `Comparator` which compares emergency numbers and, only if they are the same, compares arrival times.

Comment: I did some modifications just now but it just showed the same result.

Comment: You claim to have changed `EmergencyCmp`, but `main` is using `QueueCmp`.